# facet_wrap includes too many dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm not sure how to make reproducible data, but I'm hoping I can explain it fully.

I have data that looks like this:

```
Station       Date Presence       YrMn
1     EMB 2015-05-24        1 2015-05-01
2     EMB 2015-05-25        1 2015-05-01
3     EMB 2015-05-26        1 2015-05-01
4     EMB 2015-05-27        1 2015-05-01
5     EMB 2015-05-28        1 2015-05-01
6     EMB 2015-05-29        1 2015-05-01
```

where Date goes through 2015-2017, and Presence includes 1 (Presence), 0 (Absent) and ? (Unknown).

I have graphed it successfully to look like this

```
ggplot(subset(ALL, Station=="STF"& Presence=="1"), aes(x=YrMn, fill = factor(Presence))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", labels = dte_formatter)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F8766D"), name="Daily Presence", labels=c("Yes") )+
  geom_rect(
    fill = "light grey", alpha = .3, 
    xmin = as.Date("2016-04-19"),
    xmax = as.Date("2016-09-16"),
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = Inf)+
  ylim(0,30)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

However, once I add facet_wrap to include the years I either get:

```
ggplot(subset(ALL, Station=="STF"& Presence=="1"), aes(x=YrMn, fill = factor(Presence))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", labels = dte_formatter, expand = c(0,-20))+
  facet_wrap(~year(Date), nrow=1, scales= "fixed")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F8766D"), name="Daily Presence", labels=c("Yes") )+
  geom_rect(
    fill = "light grey", alpha = .3, 
    xmin = as.Date("2016-04-19"),
    xmax = as.Date("2016-09-16"),
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = Inf)+
  ylim(0,30)+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing=unit(0.1,"cm"))
```

[image]

Or

```
ggplot(subset(ALL, Station=="STF"& Presence=="1"), aes(x=YrMn, fill = factor(Presence))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", labels = dte_formatter, expand = c(0,-20))+
  facet_wrap(~year(Date), nrow=1, scales = "free_x")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F8766D"), name="Daily Presence", labels=c("Yes") )+
  geom_rect(
    fill = "light grey", alpha = .3, 
    xmin = as.Date("2016-04-19"),
    xmax = as.Date("2016-09-16"),
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = Inf)+
  ylim(0,30)+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing=unit(0.1,"cm"))
```

[image]

Any suggestions on how to get the year labels while still maintaining a credible graph?

Comment: OP, can you be more specific on how you want your graph to look?  Additionally, can you provide a better example of your dataset or another built-in example dataset that illustrates better the question you have?

Comment: I'd like my graph to look like my first one, but include the year underneath. I'm not sure how to include/what preset data will create similar graphs